# Why "scope link" ipv6 address can be pinged via interfaces which they are not active on

Tags: linux, ipv6, rhel6, link-local

**[root@2_01 ~]# /sbin/ip -6 addr show pubeth0**

```
inet6 2001:1::6/64 scope global
inet6 2001:1::1/64 scope global
inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8/64 scope link
```

**[root@v2_01 ~]# /sbin/ip -6 addr show pubeth1**

```
inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f906/64 scope link
```

**[root@2_01 ~]# ping6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8%pubeth1**

```
PING fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8%pubeth1(fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.259 ms
--- fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8%pubeth1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 286ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.259/0.259/0.259/0.000 ms
```

**[root@2_01 ~]# ping6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8%pubeth0**

```
PING fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8%pubeth0(fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.057 ms 
--- fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8%pubeth0 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 390ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.057/0.057/0.057/0.000 ms
```

**Why can I ping6 "fe80::20c:29ff:fe69:f9e8" via pubeth1?**

Comment: Which OS is this? I cannot reproduce the symptoms on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: [root@2_01 ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)

Comment: Could you include output of `cat /proc/version`?

Comment: [root@2_01 ~]# cat /proc/version 

Linux version 2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 
(mockbuild@x86-027.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) 
(gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) 
(GCC) ) #1 SMP Mon Mar 3 13:32:45 EST 2014

Comment: I realized this behavior might not only depend on the kernel but also on the `ping6` command. This is due to `ping6` doing a few things on its own that other programs let the kernel do. May be worth checking if the problem affects other programs like for example `ssh`.

Comment: Maybe a silly question but are the two interfaces plugged into the same network link?